# Can Windows be configured to select hyphenated words on double-click?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry

I want to be able to select hyphenated words. For example:

Double-click.

I know that I can double-click and drag, or even triple click. But, dragging is slower and triple-clicking grabs an entire sentence.

Is there any sort of change, whether in the registry or elsewhere, that would allow this behavior to be configured in Windows?

Comment: Windows has no such global setting. Which is your main application?

Comment: If you must do this for a large number of words. you could replace hyphen with an unusual letter combo, e.g., *qq*, search/ replace the hyphen-ated words,and then revert *qq* to hyphen.

Comment: I do not have a main application, this desire ranges from excel to notepad to e-mail. But if there is no solution, then perhaps a macro will be required. I was just hoping for an actual setting.